# Display Azure Devops Pipeline test success percentage on summary page

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, testcafe

After the run of an Azure Devops pipeline is complete, I get to this page, I can see the test results when I click on Tests. My question is, can I see the percentage of the succeeded testsets for every agent job in a new column right next to Status and Duration? It will be useful to see the success percentage for every agent job on the summary page.

[Screenshot of my pipeline result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ORr.png)

Comment: Hi @The Rocket, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions. If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Azure Pipelines Summary page and the Jobs grid view are not customizable. Please take a look at the following discussion: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/409247/customization-of-project-default-screen-project-su.html